# jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'participant' is undefined

Tags: javascript, twilio

I'm trying to build a video chat webapp using Twilio following https://www.twilio.com/blog/build-video-chat-application-python-javascript-twilio-programmable-video, but I keep getting the error listed in the title. From what I've gathered, I'm trying to call upon the attributes of an object (sid, name) that was never really defined (participant), but I'm not sure where in my code to define it.

```
<body>
        <h1>join existing jam</h1>
        <form>
            <label for="username">Name: </label>
            <input type="text" name="username" id="username">
            <button id="join_leave">join</button>
        </form>
        <p id="count"></p>
        <div id="container" class="container">
            <div id="local" class="participant"><div></div><div>Me</div></div>
            <div id="{{ participant.sid }}" class="participant">
                <div></div> <!-- the video and audio tracks will be attached to this div -->
                <div>{{participant.name}}</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="//media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/video/releases/2.3.0/twilio-video.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            let connected=false;
            const usernameInput = document.getElementById('username');
            const button = document.getElementById('join_leave');
            const container = document.getElementById('container');
            const count = document.getElementById('count');
            
            let room;
            
            function addLocalVideo() {
                Twilio.Video.createLocalVideoTrack().then(track => {
                    let video = document.getElementById('local').firstChild;
                    video.appendChild(track.attach());
                });
            };
            function connectButtonHandler(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                if (!connected) {
                    let username = usernameInput.value;
                    if (!username) {
                        alert('Enter your name before connecting');
                        return;
                    }
                    button.disabled = true;
                    button.innerHTML = 'connecting...';
                    connect(username).then(() => {
                        button.innerHTML = 'leave';
                        button.disabled = false;
                    }).catch(() => {
                        alert('Connection failed. Is the backend running?');
                        button.innerHTML = 'join';
                        button.disabled = false;    
                    });
                }
                else {
                    disconnect();
                    button.innerHTML = 'join';
                    connected = false;
                }
            };
            
            function connect(username) {
                let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                    // get a token from the back end
                    fetch('/login', {
                        method: 'POST',
                        body: JSON.stringify({'username': username})
                    }).then(res => res.json()).then(data => {
                        // join video call
                        return Twilio.Video.connect(data.token);
                    }).then(_room => {
                        room = _room;
                        room.participants.forEach(participantConnected);
                        room.on('participantConnected', participantConnected);
                        room.on('participantDisconnected', participantDisconnected);
                        connected = true;
                        updateParticipantCount();
                        resolve();
                    }).catch(() => {
                        reject();
                    });
                });
                return promise;
            };
            
            function updateParticipantCount() {
                if (!connected)
                    count.innerHTML = 'Disconnected.';
                else
                    count.innerHTML = (room.participants.size + 1) + ' participants online.';
            };
            
            function participantConnected(participant) {
                let participantDiv = document.createElement('div');
                participantDiv.setAttribute('id', participant.sid);
                participantDiv.setAttribute('class', 'participant');

                let tracksDiv = document.createElement('div');
                participantDiv.appendChild(tracksDiv);

                let labelDiv = document.createElement('div');
                labelDiv.innerHTML = participant.identity;
                participantDiv.appendChild(labelDiv);

                container.appendChild(participantDiv);

                participant.tracks.forEach(publication => {
                    if (publication.isSubscribed)
                        trackSubscribed(tracksDiv, publication.track);
                });
                participant.on('trackSubscribed', track => trackSubscribed(tracksDiv, track));
                participant.on('trackUnsubscribed', trackUnsubscribed);

                updateParticipantCount();
            };

            function participantDisconnected(participant) {
                document.getElementById(participant.sid).remove();
                updateParticipantCount();
            };

            function trackSubscribed(div, track) {
                div.appendChild(track.attach());
            };

            function trackUnsubscribed(track) {
                track.detach().forEach(element => element.remove());
            };
            
            function disconnect() {
                room.disconnect();
                while (container.lastChild.id != 'local')
                    container.removeChild(container.lastChild);
                button.innerHTML = 'Join call';
                connected = false;
                updateParticipantCount();
            };
            
            addLocalVideo();
            button.addEventListener('click', connectButtonHandler);
        </script>
    </body>
```

Also, if it helps, this is the app.py that I'm calling from terminal:

```
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, abort
from twilio.jwt.access_token.grants import VideoGrant

load_dotenv()
twilio_account_sid=os.environ.get("TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID")
twilio_api_key_sid = os.environ.get('TWILIO_API_KEY_SID')
twilio_api_key_secret = os.environ.get('TWILIO_API_KEY_SECRET')

app=Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('joinJam.html')

@app.route('/login',methods=['POST'])
def login():
    username=request.get_json(force=True).get('username')
    if not username:
        abort(401)

    token=AccessToken(twilio_account_sid, twilio_api_key_sid, twilio_api_key_secret, identity=username)
    token.add_grant(VideoGrant(room='My Room'))

    return {'token': token.to_jwt().decode()}
```

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Your issue is in the HTML here:

```html
<div id="container" class="container">
  <div id="local" class="participant"><div></div><div>Me</div></div>
  <div id="{{ participant.sid }}" class="participant">
    <div></div> <!-- the video and audio tracks will be attached to this div -->
    <div>{{participant.name}}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You are trying to refer to a `participant` object that does not exist.

In this case you are trying to render the participant information for the local participant. Instead of doing so directly in the HTML, you need to do this in the JavaScript once you have successfully requested the media of your local participant.

Your HTML should be:

```html
<div id="container" class="container">
  <div id="local" class="participant"><div></div><div>Me</div></div>
</div>
```

Then the showing of your media will be handled by the `addLocalVideo` method.